# PHPMD cannot run with parameters

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpmd

I've been trying to configure phpmd to work with PhpStorm, but I'm stuck here.
Here's the error I have:

> PHP Mess Detector
>   phpmd: Can not correctly run the tool with parameters:
>   C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Temp/___18.tmp/folder/myclass.php
>   xml 
>   codesize,controversial,design,naming,unusedcode
>   Possible tool process hangup after 5 sec.

I am using PhpStorm on Windows. The strange thing is that it seems to run when I do `Code > Inspect Code`, just not with live inspection.
Thing is my path isn't this one, my files are located in `C:/Users/Code/myapp`.

Can anyone help me with this error?

Comment: Sounds similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16929 -- either try increasing timeout value in Settings/Preferences from 5 sec to 10 or so .. or try configuring your PHP to not to use xdebug 9either at all or only on debug request -- see last comment in aforementioned ticket).

Answer (score 10):

In my case,the problem was that the Tool Process Timeout was setted to 5 second.
I set to 30 second and now it works fine !
We can configure it through **Languages & Framework | PHP | Mess Detector | Development Environnement | Configuration ... | Tool process timeout, sec[1..30]**

I suppose that this solution is also ok for PHP Code Sniffer

[image]